# Python: Ordering data based on date

Tags: python

I am trying to order the data below based on the date

Here is the code I have so far:

```
txt_data = """
        1. Oliver Nash, DIN-23459818, 2021-09-13, Yes, Opium,
        2. Mary Evans, DIN-23454678, 2021-09-09, Yes, Hydrocone,
        3. Michael Ye, DIN-23456678, 2021-09-12, No,
        """
        
txt_lst = []
new_lst = []
newer_lst = []
        
for line in txt_data.splitlines():
      txt_lst.append(line)
              
def extractDigits(lst):
      return [[el] for el in lst]
        
new_lst = extractDigits(txt_lst)
        
for string in new_lst:
    for item in txt_data.split(','):
        newer_lst.append(item.strip())
        
# print(txt_lst[1])
# print(new_lst[1])
print(newer_lst)
```

`print(newer_lst[1][0])` gives `D`

I am having a hard time removing the line which contains "No" and getting the date. I wanted something like `new_lst[1][2]` which should give`DIN-23459818` or `new_lst[1][3]` which would be `2021-09-13`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so what you are basically trying is to convert this string to a list containing lists with the arguments in it? (i'm just asking, not that i spend time answering the question wrongly)

Comment: Yes, essentially. I'm trying to put each line into a list element and then be able to access each term of the element, eg. `lst[1][3]` would be the date of the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
from datetime import datetime

txt_data = """
        1. Oliver Nash, DIN-23459818, 2021-09-13, Yes, Opium,
        2. Mary Evans, DIN-23454678, 2021-09-09, Yes, Hydrocone,
        3. Michael Ye, DIN-23456678, 2021-09-12, No,
        """

date_format = r'%Y-%m-%d'


lst = [l for line in txt_data.splitlines() if (l := line.strip())]

def key_function(x):
    date_string = x.split(',')[2].lstrip()
    date = datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)
    return date

lst.sort(key=key_function)

for i in lst:
    print(i)
```

output :

```
2. Mary Evans, DIN-23454678, 2021-09-09, Yes, Hydrocone,
3. Michael Ye, DIN-23456678, 2021-09-12, No,
1. Oliver Nash, DIN-23459818, 2021-09-13, Yes, Opium,
```

explanation :

First I splited the text into separate lines and I only accepted non-empty lines after stripping them. Then I sorted the list with the help of `key_function` which gets the date part of each line and creates a datetime object with `strptime`. Datetime objects are comparable so you will get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things wrong with your code. Here's what I see is *currently* happening in your code.

1. Basic variables are declared
2. `txt_data` is split into this and saved as `txt_lst`:

```py
['', '        1. Oliver Nash, DIN-23459818, 2021-09-13, Yes, Opium,', '        2. Mary Evans, DIN-23454678, 2021-09-09, Yes, Hydrocone,', '        3. Michael Ye, DIN-23456678, 2021-09-12, No,', '        ']
```

3. A function `extractDigits` is defined which wraps each element of a list into a list of length 1.
4. `extractDigits` is called to create `new_lst`, which is then this:

```py
[[''], ['        1. Oliver Nash, DIN-23459818, 2021-09-13, Yes, Opium,'], ['        2. Mary Evans, DIN-23454678, 2021-09-09, Yes, Hydrocone,'], ['        3. Michael Ye, DIN-23456678, 2021-09-12, No,'], ['        ']]
```

5. Each list of length 1 is pulled from `new_lst` and temporarily named `string`, then never used again.
6. For each iteration in step 5, your original `txt_data` is split by commas into this, then iterated over:

```py
['\n        1. Oliver Nash', ' DIN-23459818', ' 2021-09-13', ' Yes', ' Opium', '\n        2. Mary Evans', ' DIN-23454678', ' 2021-09-09', ' Yes', ' Hydrocone', '\n        3. Michael Ye', ' DIN-23456678', ' 2021-09-12', ' No', '\n        ']
```

7. For each iteration in step 6, you strip the given string and put them all into one big list, repeated for every iteration of step 5, which makes `newer_lst` be this:

```py
['1. Oliver Nash', 'DIN-23459818', '2021-09-13', 'Yes', 'Opium', '2. Mary Evans', 'DIN-23454678', '2021-09-09', 'Yes', 'Hydrocone', '3. Michael Ye', 'DIN-23456678', '2021-09-12', 'No', '', '1. Oliver Nash', 'DIN-23459818', '2021-09-13', 'Yes', 'Opium', '2. Mary Evans', 'DIN-23454678', '2021-09-09', 'Yes', 'Hydrocone', '3. Michael Ye', 'DIN-23456678', '2021-09-12', 'No', '', '1. Oliver Nash', 'DIN-23459818', '2021-09-13', 'Yes', 'Opium', '2. Mary Evans', 'DIN-23454678', '2021-09-09', 'Yes', 'Hydrocone', '3. Michael Ye', 'DIN-23456678', '2021-09-12', 'No', '', '1. Oliver Nash', 'DIN-23459818', '2021-09-13', 'Yes', 'Opium', '2. Mary Evans', 'DIN-23454678', '2021-09-09', 'Yes', 'Hydrocone', '3. Michael Ye', 'DIN-23456678', '2021-09-12', 'No', '', '1. Oliver Nash', 'DIN-23459818', '2021-09-13', 'Yes', 'Opium', '2. Mary Evans', 'DIN-23454678', '2021-09-09', 'Yes', 'Hydrocone', '3. Michael Ye', 'DIN-23456678', '2021-09-12', 'No', '']
```

8. `print(newer_lst[1][0])` gives you `D` because `newer_lst[1]` is 'DIN-23459818'`, and then index` 0` of that is the first letter.

Do you see how that isn't doing what you would like? I believe this is what you meant for it to do:

```py
txt_data = """
        1. Oliver Nash, DIN-23459818, 2021-09-13, Yes, Opium,
        2. Mary Evans, DIN-23454678, 2021-09-09, Yes, Hydrocone,
        3. Michael Ye, DIN-23456678, 2021-09-12, No,
        """

txt_lst = txt_data.splitlines()  # split by line
new_lst = [line.split(",") for line in txt_lst]  # split each line by comma

print(new_lst[1][1])  # DIN-23459818
print(new_lst[3][2])  # 2021-09-12
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the list of dicts:

```
txt_data = """ 
  1. Oliver Nash, DIN-23459818, 2021-09-13, Yes, Opium, 
  2. Mary Evans, DIN-23454678, 2021-09-09, Yes, Hydrocone, 
  3. Michael Ye, DIN-23456678, 2021-09-12, No, 
  """ 
            

lines = txt_data.splitlines()                                                                                                                                                        

lines                                                                                                                                                                                

['',
'        1. Oliver Nash, DIN-23459818, 2021-09-13, Yes, Opium,',
'        2. Mary Evans, DIN-23454678, 2021-09-09, Yes, Hydrocone,',
'        3. Michael Ye, DIN-23456678, 2021-09-12, No,',
'        ']

list1 = []                                                                                                                                                                     

for l in lines: 
    spl = [x.strip() for x in l.split(',')]
    if len(spl)<5: continue 
    d = {} 
    d['name'] = spl[0] 
    d['number'] = spl[1] 
    d['date'] = spl[2] 
    d['yn'] = spl[3] 
    d['stuff'] = spl[4] 
    list1.append(d)

list2 = sorted(list1, key=lambda x: x['date'])                                                                                                                                

list2                                                                                                                                                                               

[{'name': '2. Mary Evans',
'number': 'DIN-23454678',
'date': '2021-09-09',
'yn': 'Yes',
'stuff': 'Hydrocone'},
{'name': '3. Michael Ye',
'number': 'DIN-23456678',
'date': '2021-09-12',
'yn': 'No',
'stuff': ''},
{'name': '1. Oliver Nash',
'number': 'DIN-23459818',
'date': '2021-09-13',
'yn': 'Yes',
'stuff': 'Opium'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for this, which is especially useful if you want to do some additional data processing:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

txt_data = """
        1. Oliver Nash, DIN-23459818, 2021-09-13, Yes, Opium,
        2. Mary Evans, DIN-23454678, 2021-09-09, Yes, Hydrocone,
        3. Michael Ye, DIN-23456678, 2021-09-12, No,
        """

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt_data), names=['name', 'DIN', 'date', 'y/n', 'substance', 'empty'], skipinitialspace=True, parse_dates=['date']).drop('empty', axis=1)
df['name'] = df['name'].str.split('.').str[1].str.strip() # remove number from name column
df = df.sort_values('date').reset_index(drop=True) #sort by date
df.to_csv('output.csv') # save as csv
```

Output:

|  | name | DIN | date | y/n | substance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Mary Evans | DIN-23454678 | 2021-09-09 00:00:00 | Yes | Hydrocone |
| 1 | Michael Ye | DIN-23456678 | 2021-09-12 00:00:00 | No | nan |
| 2 | Oliver Nash | DIN-23459818 | 2021-09-13 00:00:00 | Yes | Opium |

Answer (score 0):

One way with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
txt_data = """
        1. Oliver Nash, DIN-23459818, 2021-09-13, Yes, Opium,
        2. Mary Evans, DIN-23454678, 2021-09-09, Yes, Hydrocone,
        3. Michael Ye, DIN-23456678, 2021-09-12, No,
        """

t_list = list(map(str.strip, txt_data.split(",\n")))
simple_list = []
for r in t_list:
    if r != '':
        simple_list.append(r.split(","))

df=pd.DataFrame(simple_list,columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']).sort_values(by='col3', ascending=False).values.tolist()
print(df)
```